# SQL_ID, CBO, Optimizer_Mode and Plan Change History

Tags: sql, performance, oracle, oracle10g, database-performance

This is a 4 part question

1. What is the logic behind SQL_ID. . . Does the value change for the same SQL over time? Does it persists between DB Restarts? Or every plan change gives a new SQL_ID?
2. How can i check the plan change history for a particular query? Given the SQL_ID i tried querying dba_hist_sqlstat table but it does not give the time of plan change and other details so as to be able to match with the v$sql_plan table.
3. I have the parameter optimizer_mode set to FIRST_ROWS. Even then when is see the table dba_hist_sqlstat, it indicate ALL_ROWS for some SQL_IDs . . . Can oracle disregard the instance level parameter to use what it deems most suitable?
4. Between 8PM and 2 PM a query was performing badly. Taking 6 seconds for its execution. After 3 PM the query started responding in < 1 Second. I have the AWR report for the periods that shows this detail. There was no difference in load on the DB in these 2 periods. How could i arrive at the root of this? I am trying to find the History of the plan change but appreciate more feedback to best analyze such issues.

The DB Version is Oracle 10.1.0.4 running on AIX 5.3 64b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.- SQLID is calculated with a hash function based on the actual SQL text, it shouldnt change with restart or between databases at least the same versions, different oracle versions could have different hashing functions right?, so as long as you do not change the sql text (this includes blanks commas and everything) SQLID will remain the same.

2.- Use [DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY_AWR](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_xplan.htm#i999706) to display all plans for a SQL_ID: `select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_awr(sql_id => '[your SQL_ID]'));`

3.- Oracle will only do this if a query has an OPTIMIZER GOAL hint in it.

4.- There are many things in play for this one. I would start by looking at top 5 timed events in AWR for both periods of time. If they are alike, I would then go investigate the PLAN history for the statement, see if it changed during periods and how data behaved during the periods as well. One of these three should give you the answer.